# MySQL: How to display 2 u_names from an 'expenses' table which contains 2 users displays (Pulling 2 different rows from 'users' table)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to build an expenses request system where a user can request from a supervisor for an expense.

So I have a users table:

```
u_id - primary key
u_name 
u_email 
u_password 
u_permissions 
u_sp (if supervisor [Boolean])
```

and an expenses table:

```
exp_id - primary key  
exp_user (index - contains the user ID)   
exp_sp (index - contains the user ID) 
exp_date
exp_amount
```

I want to display a table with the expenses but instead of showing the id's of both users (`exp_user` and `exp_sv`) - I want to display their name for a more comfortable view.

I thought of using JOIN as usual (Ex: `SELECT * FROM expenses JOIN users ON expenses.exp_user=users.u_id`) but I noticed that I need a different one for (`exp_sv`) so this wont work. How do I get this query right with a way to distinguish between the 2 rows from the same `users` table?

I use CodeIgniter so this is the current code part in my model:

```
// Get "expenses" table  from DB.
public function get_expenses_table() { 

    /*$query = $this->db->get('expenses');
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;*/

    $query - $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM expenses 
                                                JOIN users 
                                                ON expenses.exp_user=users.u_id ");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join them like this:

```
SELECT 
    e.*, 
    u1.u_name user_name,
    u2.u_name supervisor_name
FROM expenses e
LEFT JOIN users u1 on u1.u_id = e.exp_user
LEFT JOIN users u2 on u2.u_id = e.exp_sp
```

Comment: I get this error: 
`Unknown column 'u1.name' in 'field list' SELECT e.*, u1.name user_name, u2.name supervisor_name FROM expenses e LEFT JOIN users u1 on u1.u_id = e.exp_user LEFT JOIN users u2 on u2.u_id = e.exp_sp`

Comment: I tried running this directly on phpmyadmins console and this works! 

The this is that CI gives me errors for some strange reason: 

`Undefined variable: query` and `Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to int` on this line: `LEFT JOIN users u2 on u2.u_id = e.exp_sp` and an error on the command after it which is: `$result = $query->result();` ==> this errors: `Undefined variable: query` and `Call to a member function result() on null`

Comment: from your code above: `$query - $this->db->query('SELECT ....`. is this just a typo error?

Comment: good catch! :) 

Just before I continue I want to get a deeper understand of what you did. 
I have never used variables (are they vars?) in SQL. What do I need to google to get more deep information about what you did here?

Comment: that's alias, you can read more about that here [https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
 SELECT e.exp_id,e.exp_user,e.exp_sp,e.exp_date,e.exp_amount,
 u.u_name 
 FROM expenses e,users u
 where e.exp_user=u.u_id
```

Comment: I think it's missing here the exp_sv part.